# Does it make sense to apply for assistant professorship positions before Ph.D. graduation?

Tags: united-states, job-search, tenure-track, canada, assistant-professor

In the course of browsing a couple of positions for brand-new (STEM-related) assistant professorships (in North America), I am wondering whether it does make sense if one applies for such positions before her Ph.D. graduation. For example, an advertisement asserts that

> These positions require a Ph.D. or equivalent in engineering or a
> closely related discipline **at date of hire**

The job announcement has only supplied a period for application submissions, say, Nov. 2020 until May 2021. My Ph.D. defense is around early 2021, but I think if I wait till that time, the positions may have already been occupied without any chance of competition for me. But if I act before graduation, will my potential application be considered when I have not yet sealed my Ph.D.?

Comment: I think you could reasonably email the contact person listed in the advert and ask them this question.

Comment: @avid absolutely not. People who advertise positions can’t comment on your chances of being offered a position, for legal and ethical reasons. They will just tell you you are free to apply if you satisfy the minimum requirements.

Comment: @DanRomik Indeed. But at least part of this question boils down to "please clarify precisely what your minimum requirements are".

Comment: @avid the language of the job ad is perfectly clear. An applicant will need to have a PhD at date of hire. There isn’t anything more to say on the subject of minimum requirements.

Comment: Regarding the "date of hire" requirement: If they want to hire you, they can probably set up the contract to start a few months later, when you have your PhD.

Comment: Depends if you want a job after graduation...

Comment: "Date of hire" means "start date" not "date offer issued"

Comment: @avid From my side of the table, if I state VERY clearly you have to have a PhD once the contract starts (and it's a teaching position, so the term is very clear when it starts), and then you're either too clueless or wordblind to read this so you start bugging me with unneeded emails, I make a note that this person will be a nightmare to work with/against/above.

Comment: That said, the academic job market is such a massacre at the moment that you can hire someone that should easily be associate prof but for the salary of a lecturer; you'll need to bring something to the table that the others with their PhD and many years of teaching are lacking.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Most people apply for positions while still students. That is normal. The "date of hire" could mean various things, depending on the institution. Don't worry too much about it, and apply. If there is any sort of issue they might be able to finesse it a bit, but likely they intend that early 2021 graduates are part of their intended outreach.

The date of hire is not usually interpreted as the date you get an acceptance letter, but the date you actually become an employee (with a paycheck).

Comment: "Most people apply for positions while still students."  But most engineering PhD students do NOT have a chance at getting an assistant professorship.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist Depends on the type of school. For an R1 you are correct; for a primarily teaching school, on the other hand...

Comment: @BryanKrause Check recent faculty profiles in engineering, and I think you will find I am correct almost everywhere.  Engineering schools are overwhelmingly at R1s anyway.

Comment: Not every program with engineering faculty is part of a true "engineering school".

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist this may be country specific. For instance in India, a PhD suffices in almost all universities to get an assistant professorship.

Comment: *Most people apply for positions while still students.* --- For departments I'm familiar with (U.S., 1980s-2000s, math), "most" is "virtually every". Where I got my Ph.D. there were several of us on track to finish that year (you pretty much knew this by late Fall of that academic year). Since the ads had deadlines roughly Dec. to March, and graduation wasn't until May (or sometimes July), there was no choice. I think most offers had clauses saying tenure-track reverted to a 1-year position if your Ph.D. wasn't awarded by a certain date. **(continued)**

Comment: Usually, however, final orals were done by the time an offer was made, so there only remained bureaucratic formalities and waiting until the next graduation date for it to be official. In my case (tenure-track), the interview was in March, I was hired in April or early May, final orals were in April or May (don't remember), I didn't formally submit my dissertation until mid July (I was adding a lot of extra historical and bibliographic material until the last minute), I began the tenure-track position in August, and the official awarding of my degree wasn't until December.

Answer (score 9):

**Talk to your advisor.**

It is absolutely possible for a person to get hired for a tenure track position straight out of their PhD (and when that happens, the person must have applied before they graduated). I know several people who had that happen to them. So in that sense, you are overthinking things. However, I’ll repeat: talk to your advisor. Just because something is possible doesn’t mean it’s likely, and the likelihood and difficulty of securing a position in such circumstances will vary wildly between research areas, countries, and different tiers of universities in any given country.

So again, sorry to sound like a broken record, but you’ll have to ask your advisor to find out whether applying to such jobs makes sense in your situation or not.

Comment: "I know several people who had that happen to them."  Were they engineers?  Was this in the past decade?  And are they a tiny minority of new faculty?

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist they were mathematicians, and this was around 8-12 years ago. But I think those data points are beside the point. The main points I am trying to convey are: 1. It can and does happen. 2. We can’t advise OP on whether it is a realistic thing to aim for given their specific situation.

Comment: I agree it does happen but I think we should be clear it only happens in engineering under special, unlikely circumstances.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist if you say so. I don’t consider myself qualified to comment about that.

Answer (score 2):

The job listing says

> These positions require a Ph.D....at **date of hire**

So the requirement raises one question: *Will the applicant have the degree, at the date of hire*?

> But if I act before graduation, *will my potential application be considered when I have not yet sealed my Ph.D.*?

Yes, your application will be considered *if it notes that you will have your degree on the date of hire* because you will then satisfy the requirement found in the job listing.

This obviously makes you responsible for sealing your Ph.D. If a job applicant asserts that the applicant will seal a Ph.D. then whoever assesses that applicant's application will assume the applicant is correct.

Answer (score -1):

In the 21st century, > 90% of assistant professors of engineering (and other STEM fields I am familiar with) have a PhD in hand and postdoctoral experience before they get their job.

Even if you already have completed your PhD, you face steep competition.

> These positions require a Ph.D. or equivalent in engineering or a closely related discipline at date of hire

This statement is traditional boilerplate which in no way indicates the (much more difficult to get) qualifications needed to actually get the job.

Note that in some humanities fields, it is traditional *not* to hire people who already have PhDs as assistant professors.

Comment: 'Note that in some humanities fields, it is traditional not to hire people who already have PhDs as assistant professors.' Could you explain why?

Comment: @JonasSchwarz No, no idea.  Second hand information.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist then it's maybe is worth to remove the sentence? I can hardly imagine an assistant professor _without_ a PhD, so a quotation would be highly appreciated.

Comment: @Mayou36 You've misunderstood; the assistant professors usually have PhDs.  They got them after they were hired but before they started the job.  I don't do reference requests, I'm sure you can google the data as well as I can.

Comment: I strongly suspect there is not a good reason for the tradition.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist I suspect the reason for the tradition is that there is an oversupply of PhDs and that people with successful post-docs are more competitive candidates.  Whether that is a good reason or not is an exercise for the reader.

Comment: AP, can your last sentence be recast as "traditional to hire people who don't have PhDs yet as assistant professors"? I think that would make the meaning clearer, if that's what you intend.

Comment: Unless you can back your last sentence you should remove it.  I actually do not think this is a tradition or generally true, but I’d be happy to learn otherwise.

Comment: I'd really wish people would stop pestering me with reference requests.  This is quite easy information to find.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist People pester you with reference requests, and downvote and even flag your answers, because you make many "general" claims which are actually not generally true by the experience of many, experience which, for some, is probably much longer and broader than yours. So, try to reflect on this and make an effort to improve your answers.

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano I have no complaints about the downvotes.  Furthermore, I have almost never chosen to give answers which require effort on my part and I see no way I could be convinced to do so.  Please stop asking.  Use the downvote button instead.

Comment: Also, if you don't think my claims are true and you can't check with minimal research, I do encourage you to post a new question.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist You fail to understand that it's not me: the complaints arrive from many different users, and these users will keep on complaining until you don't improve your answers.

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano I @ mentioned you, but I did not think it's you.  People are not entitled to answers, with our without references.  They are entitled to downvote.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist people are not entitled to answers, but they entitled to use the flagging mechanism, and it’s the moderators’ role to deal with flags regarding answers that make dubious claims. Of course no one can force you to do anything you don’t want to do, but don’t pretend that there can’t be consequences to making irresponsible claims in your answers.

Comment: @DanRomik If you can explain why an answer could cause harm I would delete it.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist spreading misinformation has the obvious potential to cause harm in many different ways. In the specific context of academia.se it can cause people to make incorrect career decisions for example.

Comment: @DanRomik That's not what I asked for.  Specific harm particular to a specific answer.  Don't tell me discouraging engineering PhD students from applying for engineering assistant professorships causes harm, because on average it does not.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist I was mostly referring to the last sentence of your answer - the baseless remark about the humanities that everyone here is complaining about. As for the engineering issue, I don’t think your advice is terribly helpful to OP (a specific person, who may very well not be “average”), which is probably why your answer was downvoted (fair game according to you). But that doesn’t rise to a level that requires a moderator’s intervention or for you to delete your answer because of, so again that’s not what my comment was addressing.